# uib-popover-template do not show data inside

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use a uib-popover-template. It worked before, but now empty popup without data(can't attach img). How can i fix this issue? Code below

```html
<div class="subject"
   uib-popover-template="'popover.html'"
   popover-placement="bottom-left"
   popover-trigger="'outsideClick'">
  <a>{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</a>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="popover.html">
  <div class="media">
    <div class="media-left">
      <img class="user-icon" ng-src="{{user.actions.server}}storage/user/mini/{{user.user.avatar}}" />
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}
    </div>
 </div>
</script>
```

Comment: any error come?

Comment: no just empty popup

Answer (score 0):

The [ng-src directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) works better with just one interpolation binding:

```
<!-- REPLACE 
<img ng-src="{{user.actions.server}}storage/user/mini/{{user.user.avatar}}" />
-->

<!-- INSTEAD -->
<img  ng-src="{{user.actions.server +'storage/user/mini/'+ user.user.avatar}}" />
```

Comment: It looks better. Thanks